# Continuous Image of a Closed Interval is Closed.

Tags: real-analysis

$f:A\to \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function, where $A$ is a closed set which is also an interval. Then $f(A)$ is also a closed set as well as an interval.

Is the statement true?

$A$ may not be bounded, that is $A$ can be of the form $[a,\infty)$

If I take $A:=(-\infty,\infty)=\mathbb{R}$ then this is not true. Because there are functions from $\mathbb{R}$ whose image is $(0,1)$.

So If $A$ is a proper closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, is the statement true?

Comment: A closed interval is always of the form $[a, b] $ with real numbers $a, b$ and $a\leq b$. Don't confuse that with "any closed set which is also an interval".

Comment: The statement is true under the interpretation of previous comment.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: Can you give some hint to prove the statement

Comment: This is a standard result based on three famous properties of continuous functions: boundedness, IVT, extreme value theorem. See https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-boundedness-property.html?m=0 and https://paramanands.blogspot.com/2011/06/continuous-functions-on-closed-interval-intermediate-value-theorem.html?m=0

Comment: @ParamanandSingh: I have edited my question. Please see it now.

Comment: For your edited version, image of a closed set under continuous function is not necessarily closed. However if inverse image of a closed set under continuous map is a closed set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A = [0, \infty)$ and $f(x) = \arctan(x)$. Then $f(A) = [0, \pi/2)$, which is not a closed interval.

The result is true if $A$ is a *compact* (closed and bounded) interval, in which case $f(A)$ is also a closed and bounded interval.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $f$ attains its maximal $K$ and minimal $T$ on closed interval $A$, and then use intermediate value theorem to conclude that $f$ attains  every $t \in [T,K]$ on $A$.

Comment: What about $f(x)=\arctan(x),$ $A=\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I don't think R is a closed interval.

Comment: Of course $\mathbb R$ is a closed interval. To address the OP's request for a counterexample where $A$ is a proper subset of $\mathbb R$, you can take $A = [0, \infty)$ and $f(x) = \arctan(x)$.

Comment: @Bungo: I prefer to say that $\mathbb {R} $ is closed set, but not a closed interval. A closed interval is a term introduced early on in math curriculum when students don't have any idea of topology stuff like open and closed sets.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh The OP is clearly allowing $[0,\infty)$ as a closed interval (he/she says as much explicitly), so in this context I think it's appropriate to include $\mathbb R$ as well. Just curious, is there a textbook out there which does *not* consider $\mathbb R$ to be an interval?

Comment: @Bungo : I understand your point. Also $\mathbb{R}$ is a closed set as well as an interval but together they don't make it a "closed interval". In order to sort out this confusion, analysts have introduced a new term called "compact interval".

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I'm afraid I don't see why "closed set" and "interval" do not imply "closed interval". I'm not sure your usage is standard. Yes, compact interval is standard terminology and unambiguous, but it's not a synonym for a "closed set" that is also an "interval", as compact also implies bounded. Anyway, the OP explicitly states that "$A$ may not be bounded" and names both $\mathbb R$ and $[0,\infty)$ as examples so at least in his context I think they qualify :-)

Comment: @Bungo Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2451160, and also Topology by Munkres, page 84, chapter 2, section 14 the order topology. "Given elements $a, b$ of $X$ such that $a<b$"...

Comment: Since $+ \infty$ and $- \infty$ are not elements of $\mathbb{R}$, so $\mathbb{R}$ can't be of the form $[a,b]$, hence $\mathbb{R}$ is not a closed interval.

Comment: Do you remember in precalculus when you had to express the domain of a function in *interval* notation? Endpoints could definitely be $\pm \infty$. Just look here: https://www.coolmath.com/algebra/15-functions/06-finding-the-domain-01

Comment: @MatthewPilling Yes, but we can use $\infty$ as an endpoint only for open intervals. Consider if we use them to closed intervals: $[1,+\infty]=\{t\in R\cup \{+- \infty\} :  1\leq t \leq + \infty \}$. Then we have $+\infty \in [1, +\infty]$, which we don't want to.

Comment: @cxh007 $[0,\infty)$ is a closed interval. It contains all of its accumulation points.

Comment: @MatthewPilling Please check this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036385/does-0-infty-counts-for-a-closed-interval-in-extended-real-number-system

Comment: @cxh007 [Your linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036385/does-0-infty-counts-for-a-closed-interval-in-extended-real-number-system) asks whether $\mathbb R$ and $[0,\infty)$ are closed subsets of the **extended** real numbers $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$. Clearly they are not. But the OP is explicitly asking about subsets of $\mathbb R$, not of $\mathbb R \cup \{-\infty, +\infty\}$.

Comment: @Bungo You're right, I get it. Now I am going to think about just $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @Bungo please see this:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4036450/does-0-infty-counts-for-a-closed-interval-in-just-real-number-system