# Does $[0,+ \infty)$ counts for a closed interval in extended real number system?

Tags: solution-verification, definition, real-numbers

In Topology by Munkres, page 84, chapter 2, section 14 the order topology:
[image]

So, we are discussing the situation when $X=\mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty, -\infty\}$. Then $[0,+\infty):= \{t\in X: 0 \leq t < +\infty \}$, it is not of the form $[a,b]:= \{t \in X: a\leq t \leq b \}$, hence $[0, +\infty)$ is not a closed interval. And this example disprove the statement: "a closed interval is an interval which is also a closed set". Also, above reasoning shows that for any $a\in X, [a,+\infty), (-\infty, a]$ and $\mathbb{R} = (-\infty,+\infty)$ are not closed intervals.

Is there any flaw in my understanding?

Answer (score 1):

$[0,+\infty)$ is a semi-open interval in the extended real line with respect to the order topology. For some $M>0$, consider the neighborhood $N=\{x \in X : x>M\}$ of $+\infty$, then $N$ intersects $[0,+\infty)$ and thus $+\infty$ is limit point of $[0,+\infty)$.

Same reason applies to the rest of the sets.